# This seems ok ,please correct me

Tags: oracle, plsql

```sql
n number := &n;
c number;
i number;
function isprime(x in number)
    RETURN number
    IS
begin
    count number:=0;
    for i in 2..x/2 loop
        if mod(x,i)=0 then
            count := count+1;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return count;
end;

begin
    c:=isprime(n);
    if c=0 then
        dbms_output.put_line(n||'is a prime number');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line(n||'is not prime');
    end if;
end;
/
```

> ORA-06550: line 11, column 7:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMBER" when expecting one of the following:
> := . ( @ % ;
> The symbol "." was substituted for "NUMBER" to continue.

Comment: You are missing the `DECLARE` keyword.

Comment: Format your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use column names that match Oracle's built-in functions (`count` is one of them). Declare variables in *declaration section*, not just *anywhere*.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     n  NUMBER := &par_n;
  3     c  NUMBER;
  4     i  NUMBER;
  5
  6     FUNCTION isprime (x IN NUMBER)
  7        RETURN NUMBER
  8     IS
  9        l_count  NUMBER := 0;
 10     BEGIN
 11        FOR i IN 2 .. x / 2
 12        LOOP
 13           IF MOD (x, i) = 0
 14           THEN
 15              l_count := l_count + 1;
 16           END IF;
 17        END LOOP;
 18
 19        RETURN l_count;
 20     END;
 21  BEGIN
 22     c := isprime (n);
 23
 24     IF c = 0
 25     THEN
 26        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (n || ' is a prime number');
 27     ELSE
 28        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (n || ' is not prime');
 29     END IF;
 30  END;
 31  /
Enter value for par_n: 6
6 is not prime

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for par_n: 7
7 is a prime number

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```